# Java Applet Certificate

Tags: java, applet, certificate

I have an Apache Webserver with a signed certificate from StartSSL, I tried creating a Applet and now I need to sign it, but how do I do that? Do I need a new certificate, where to put what? I havent found any good explanations on Google or Oracles site.

Comment: You can start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/rsa_signing.html). Also do yourself a favor and don't use applets unless you really really have to.

Comment: @Mena  With the introduction of HTML 5 and the HTML `canvas` element, those 'really have to' times are becoming as rare as hen's teeth.  I cannot recall seeing a description of an applet (barring use of natives) that could ***not*** be achieved with HTML/JS and a `canvas`  (which is perhaps interesting in that I am the [top rated provider of answers to applet problems](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/topusers) on SO).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I agree. Of course, many enterprise products sadly take very long to catch up, so maintenance of applets is still a thing. True story.

Comment: *"maintenance of applets is still a thing"*  Yes, but it is getting to the stage where it is cheaper to cease supporting applets and instead devote that money to writing a replacement..  I have effectively 'ceased supporting' applets in the sense that I won't provide answers unless I hear from the OP that it is for a school project that specifies it.  Even then I'll ask that the student directs their teacher's attention to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).